# htaccess disallowing icons to be visible

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

To get `.htaccess` to allow `fa` icons to be visible I had made some changes.

Previously `www.mywebsite.com` the `fa` icons were not visible. I added a few lines to my `.htaccess` and it started to work.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.mywebsite.com"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
# Web fonts
AddType application/font-woff woff
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot

# Browsers usually ignore the font MIME types and sniff the content,
# however, Chrome shows a warning if other MIME types are used for the
# following fonts.
AddType application/x-font-ttf ttc ttf
AddType font/opentype otf

# Make SVGZ fonts work on iPad:
# https://twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
AddType     image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz

</IfModule>
```

Now, `mywebsite.com` (without the www) did not work. So I added

```
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://mywebsite.com"
```

Like this

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.mywebsite.com"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://mywebsite.com"

And `mywebsite.com` started to work. Now `www.mywebsite.com` has stopped working.

I am using `wordpress` for my website. What am I missing ?

**Edit**
I tried to add 3 lines based on recommendations on various forums, but I ended up getting 500 Internal error instead.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am I missing, do I need to put this code within some `<ifModule>` block ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the [rewrite module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) enabled. First, update your htaccess file to look like this:

```bsh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.mywebsite.com"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    # Web fonts
    AddType application/font-woff woff
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot

    # Browsers usually ignore the font MIME types and sniff the content,
    # however, Chrome shows a warning if other MIME types are used for the
    # following fonts.
    AddType application/x-font-ttf ttc ttf
    AddType font/opentype otf

    # Make SVGZ fonts work on iPad:
    # https://twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
    AddType     image/svg+xml svg svgz
    AddEncoding gzip svgz
</IfModule>
```

Then, make sure that the rewrite module is enabled:

```bsh
# Check if it's enabled:
apachectl -M | grep rewrite

# You might need sudo here:
a2enmod rewrite

# On platforms that a2enmod is not available, you need 
# to open up your httpd.conf file and uncomment the line
# that looks like this:
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: I tried to add `LoadModule` to `httpd.conf`, but did not find it. So I checked `mod-enabled` folder. I found rewrite.load here. I found `LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so` in this file. For some reason `a2enmod rewrite` got the website to work after the htaccess changes. Shouldn't the module load automatically since `rewrite.load` is in the `mod-enabled` folder already ?

Comment: Will I need to run `a2enmod rewrite` everytime I restart the box ?

Comment: Sorry had to undo the accept. When use `mywebsite.com`, the web browser toggles between `www.mywebsite.com` and `mywebsite.com` continuously and gives up. The website is not loading, infact its loading after a while without any graphics.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my answer. I fixed it now. See if that works for you.  If you still get in a redirection loop, you must have some other rules in your htaccess not mentioned here. And no, you don't need to `a2enmod rewrite` every time. Just enable the module once and restart the server and you're good to go.